# EFCore DotNet 5 & Automapper. Map virtual collections

Tags: .net-core, collections, entity-framework-core, automapper

Firstly, I am new to Automapper and finding the official documentation poor to say the least.

I am trying to map two complex entities with virtual collections which themselves need to be mapped

```cs
Map<IEnumerable<ComplexEntityDb>, IEnumerable<ComplexEntityVM>>
```

within each row I need to map

```cs
Map<IEnumerable<EntityCollectionItemDb>, IEnumerable<EntityCollectionItemVM>>
```

A very simplified version of the classes:

```cs
public class ComplexEntityDb
{
    public int Id;

    // Multiple properties (14) removed for brevity

    public virtual ICollection<EntityCollectionItemDb> CollectionDb { get; set; }
}

public class ComplexEntityVM
{
    public int Id;

    // Multiple properties (7) removed for brevity

    public virtual ICollection<EntityCollectionItemVM> CollectionDb { get; set; }
}


public class EntityCollectionItemDb
{
    public int Id;

    // Multiple properties (12) removed for brevity
}

public class EntityCollectionItemVM
{
    public int Id;

    // Multiple properties (6) removed for brevity
}
```

What is the correct way to do this with  EF Core 5.04 on dotnet 5 using AutoMapper 10.1.1 and DI extensions 8.1.1

I have read dozens of articles on this site and there does not seem to be an easy way to do this.

Many thanks in advance for any help much wiser souls can give.

**EDIT:** (taken from the comment section of @dglozano's answer) -

I am using mapping profile -

```cs
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile() 
    {
        CreateMap<ComplexEntityDb, ComplexEntityVM>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<EntityCollectionItemDb, EntityCollectionItemVM>).ReverseMap(); 
    } 
}
```

and IMapper -

```cs
private readonly IMapper _mapper; 

public CustomService(IMapper mapper) 
{
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

and trying -

```cs
return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ComplexEntityDb>, IEnumerable<ComplexEntityVM>>(source);
```

Result: `EntityCollectionItemVM` collection is empty.

Comment: First thing that springs to mind is that you should probably try to use `ProjectTo` instead of `Map`.

Comment: Is `source` an `IQueryable` ? or are you materializing the query results before mapping?

Comment: @MaxTheCoder so, did you figure it out?

Comment: Created new VM model by duplicating the DB model and tested the mapper and this worked as expected. So the mapping configuration was correct. @dglozano's IQueryable comment got me thinking and after a lot of head scratching, discovered that the EntityCollectionItemVM had its own child collection which was IEnumerable but its DB counterpart was ICollection. This seemed to be causing the error. Digging through documentation, ICollection inherits IEnumerable so you can map one way but not the other. Changed the DB model to IEnumerable and now works. Many thanks for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define the mappings of each element type, as [the documentation for Nested Mappings suggests](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Nested-mappings.html). You have to tell Automapper how to map `ComplexEntityDb -> ComplexEntityVM` and how to map `EntityCollectionItemDb  -> EntityCollectionItemVM`, and then all [the mappings of collections of those items will automatically be supported.](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Lists-and-arrays.html)

So in your case, a minimal example would look like this:

```
using System;
using AutoMapper;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class ComplexEntityDb
{
    public ComplexEntityDb(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
        var item1 = new EntityCollectionItemDb();
        var item2 = new EntityCollectionItemDb();
        item1.Id = id * 1000 + 1;
        item2.Id = id * 1000 + 2;
        CollectionDb = new List<EntityCollectionItemDb>{item1, item2, };
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // Multiple properties (14) removed for brevity
    public ICollection<EntityCollectionItemDb> CollectionDb
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class ComplexEntityVM
{
    public int Id;
    // Multiple properties (7) removed for brevity
    public ICollection<EntityCollectionItemVM> CollectionDb
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class EntityCollectionItemDb
{
    public int Id;
// Multiple properties (12) removed for brevity
}

public class EntityCollectionItemVM
{
    public int Id;
// Multiple properties (6) removed for brevity
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ComplexEntityDb, ComplexEntityVM>();
            cfg.CreateMap<EntityCollectionItemDb, EntityCollectionItemVM>();
        });
        var complexEntity1 = new ComplexEntityDb(1);
        var complexEntity2 = new ComplexEntityDb(2);
        var complexEntity3 = new ComplexEntityDb(3);
        var source = new List<ComplexEntityDb>{complexEntity1, complexEntity2, complexEntity3};
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        var dest = mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ComplexEntityDb>, IEnumerable<ComplexEntityVM>>(source);
        
        foreach(var parentMapped in dest)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Mapped parent Id {0}", parentMapped.Id);
            foreach(var childMapped in parentMapped.CollectionDb)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  - Mapped child Id {0}", childMapped.Id);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

```
Output:

Mapped parent Id 1
  - Mapped child Id 1001
  - Mapped child Id 1002

Mapped parent Id 2
  - Mapped child Id 2001
  - Mapped child Id 2002

Mapped parent Id 3
  - Mapped child Id 3001
  - Mapped child Id 3002
```

[Try it out in this fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d8yBLS)

In a more real scenario, it would be the same idea, but I would create a [Profile(s)](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#profile-instances) to define each of the mappings configurations and then use the injected `IMapper` to do execute the mapping.

Comment: I am using mapping profile

    public class MappingProfile : Profile
    {
        public MappingProfile()
        {

            CreateMap<ComplexEntityDb, ComplexEntityVM>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<EntityCollectionItemDb, EntityCollectionItemVM>).ReverseMap();
        }

    }

and Imapper:

private readonly IMapper _mapper;

public CustomService(IMapper mapper)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
}

and trying:
                return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ComplexEntityDb>, IEnumerable<ComplexEntityVM>>(source);

Result: EntityCollectionItemVM collection is empty.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your profile configuration there? @MaxTheCoder

Comment: @MaxTheCoder have you double checked that your source has a non empty child collection? Perhaps you are missing an `.Include(x => x.YourChildCollection)` in your EF query. Your mapping configuration seems to be correct, and you can check in the minimal fiddle example I created that the child collection is being mapped.... so if you did your query right and your source collection has the related collection loaded (Included), then the mapping should work.

Comment: I cannot edit the original question, it keeps telling me I have too much code. No amount of additional text will allow me to save.

Comment: I have verified that the source data from db correctly contains the required collections

Comment: Then most likely your are not picking your profiles correctly when adding automapper to the DI container. Can you post the code of your startup? @MaxTheCoder

Comment: @MaxTheCoder so to sum up, either you didn't configure Automapper correctly (check https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration and https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection ) or the collections from DB are also empty... but in any case, it is not a problem with your maps